# Return data from Loading screen

Tags: blackberry

I have a problem when implementing the loading screen from this page

[BlackBerry Please Wait Screen with Time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533148/blackberry-please-wait-screen-with-time-out)

It was working well, but the problem is I can't get the string data from this code.

The idea is I want to load the screen when capture json data from webservice, and return it as string. But I get stuck because the code below can't return data.

```
UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(thisScreen)
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `Interface` to achieve that. When you call the method `PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(Runnable, String)` (from the link, [BlackBerry Please Wait Screen with Time out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9533148/blackberry-please-wait-screen-with-time-out)), you can add another parameter on that method. If an Interface instance used as the third parameter, the callback method of that interface can be used to notify a `PopupScreen` close event. You can try following procedures.

Create an Interface, define callback method.

```
interface PopupScreenCloseListener {
    // Invoke this method when PopupScreen gets closed.     
    public void popupScreenClosed();
}
```

Implement the interface and append it as the third parameter of `showScreenAndWait`. Also get the PopupScreen close event notification on callback method.

```
class MyClass implements PopupScreenCloseListener {
    public void showWaitingPopupScreen(final Runnable runThis, String text) {
        // append the interface, PopupScreenCloseListener as third parameter
        PleaseWaitPopupScreen.showScreenAndWait(runThis, text, this);
    }

    public void popupScreenClosed() {
        // listen PopupScreen close event here...
        // and add codes...
    }
}
```

And modify current implementation of the method, `showScreenAndWait`.

```
public static void showScreenAndWait(final Runnable runThis, String text, final PopupScreenCloseListener listener) {
    // old codes...
    // old codes...
            // Now dismiss this screen
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(thisScreen);

                    // notify PopupScreen close event.
                    if (listener != null) {
                        listener.popupScreenClosed();
                    }

                }
            });
    // old codes...
    // old codes...
}
```